# How to make a span tag wider with an alphabet inside?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to work on a very simple logo.

[image: AngulAir]

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="text-center angulair"><span>A</span>ngul<span>A</span>ir</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
.angulair span{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #205081;
    }
```

What I want is to make the A's span tags wider so that the height and th width of the blue colour is equal. I have tried adding width into the CSS but that doesn't work. How do make the span tags wider so that the blue colour is a square?

Comment: Make `display: inline-block;` for the `span` and then assign `width`.

Comment: Oh. That was easy. I'll have to look into how that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, just using `padding` is enough:

```css
.angulair span {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #205081;
    padding:10px 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center angulair"><span>A</span>ngul<span>A</span>ir</h1>
```

Comment: Yea, probably a better option for this case.

Comment: @Harry yes, `inline-block` with _fixed_ `width` and `height` will also work, however, with using only `padding` there is less styles.

Comment: This is not a robust approach, as you need to estimate the padding needed and this may go wrong. The height of an inline element is determined by the browser and may vary depending on font, browser, etc.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I agree. I'm assuming that the OP uses some CSS reset along with optimized font. If he isn't, then `inline-block` with fixed values is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The robust way is to make the `span` element an inline block, so that your width and height settings on it will be honored. You can set the size of the box to what you want, but a natural approach is to make it match the line height (distance between baselines of text), so consider setting line height explicitly. And you probably want the letter horizontally centered, so set `text-align: center` on it.

```css
.angulair {
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.angulair span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #205081;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center angulair"><span>A</span>ngul<span>A</span>ir</h1>
```

Comment: Agreed. You have a very valid point mate. I didn't think on those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try `display:inline-block`

```css
.angulair span {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #205081;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center angulair"><span>A</span>ngul<span>A</span>ir</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use
`.angulair span{display:inline-block; width:200px;}` 
and then you can define the width of the span

```css
.angulair span {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #205081;
  // to Define a width of a span tag you can try the below CSS
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center angulair"><span>A</span>ngul<span>A</span>ir</h1>
```